# Creating a binary flag to return whether someone has used a product in the last n days

Tags: excel

I have three variables: the person using the item, the date the item was used, and the brand. I'd like to create a flag that indicates whether a specific brand (in this case, BrandA) was used in the last n days by a given person.

The Y-AA columns are an example of the data that I'm working with, and the AB column is the desired result.

Example

[image]

I know at the end I'll probably have =if( , True, False), but I'm not sure what would make up the argument.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: why is line 3 a `1` when AA is not `BrandA`?

Comment: Because BrandA was used in the last ten days by this person

Comment: then why is line 2 0?

Comment: it's because it's for a different person named jill

Comment: But in row 4 Jill is 1, so I do not see why bob in row 3 is 1 and jill in row 2 is not and for that matter why row 5 bob is 0?

Comment: In row 4, Jill has used BrandA so is 1. In row 3, Bob is 1 because he used BrandA within the last ten days. In row 5, bob has not used brandA in the last ten days so is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to consider how you're setting up your data. Below is an example of how you can create your `IF` conditions to make it work -- using data that is unclear in your post.

Set up your data like so, with cell `Z1` using the name `AnchorDate`.

[image]

Then the formula entered in cell `AB4` and copied down and across will be

```
=IF(AND($Y4=AB$1,$AA4=AB$2,DAYS(AnchorDate,$Z4)<=10),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very close to what I'm looking for. Is there any way to do it without the anchor date and just the given date in the Z column?

Comment: Replace the `AnchorDate` in the formula with `TODAY()`